# Genymostion Start with white screen

Tags: eclipse, genymotion

I have a laptop with i5 configuration and I have a PC with Intel Q33 motherboard and core2Deo. In my i5 its work fine but in Q33 first give me OpenGL error but I upgraded the graphic driver and the problem solved. But in my PC when I start a genymotion device it start with white screen and dost allow any thing to touch...

I have done following solution

- upgrade my Graphic Driver
- Reinstall VBox of oracle
- Reinstall Genymostion and download devices

so it no issue with installation of the genymostion but still i gatting white screen ...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your OpenGL Version to 2.0 or higher.
Please Check Requirement of Genymotion and check your system configuration.

Comment: i recently update my driver i think i update OpenGL support ...How Can I Check it updated or not ?? thx for answer

Comment: still get white screen

Answer (score 2):

In VMbox the android virtual machine is working. and on geymotion having the same above issue.
I have update my video card too .. using win 7

Answer (score 1):

Now I get to know that my chipshet have no updation for OpenGl.
So, It's not going to work for me.

If you want to check your Opengl version then download the below link:-
http://ononesoft.cachefly.net/support/DoctorGL.exe.zip

For instruction follow below link:-
http://www.ononesoftware.com/support/607/